# ERROR mysqli_select_db( )

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la versión *5.6 (Xamp)*, me muestra error al registrar mi formulario:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\juan\htdocs\Admin\user.php on line 106
>
> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\juan\htdocs\Admin\user.php on line 115
> Erreur SQL !

Os dejo el código:

```
// fichier de configuration 
            
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    include("config/config.php");
    $cnx = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "" ) ;
    //sélection de la base de données:
    $db  = mysqli_select_db( "$nombd" ) ;

    $login=$_POST['Login'] ;
    $pwd=$_POST['Pwd'] ;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como bien te indica el error, la función `mysqli_select_db()` espera 2 parámetros pero tu solamente le estás pasando 1.

A la función `mysql_select_db` tienes que pasarle también la conexión a la base de datos, en tu caso `$cnx`.

```
$db  = mysqli_select_db( $cnx, $nombd ) ;
```

Puedes leer más acerca de dicha función aquí:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php